# Arrange 4 divs in cascade in 4 columns

Tags: html, css

I need to arrange 4 cascading divs that look like they are in 4 columns.

This is my html structure (I can't modify it)

```
<div class="col1">
    1111
    <div class="col2">
        2222
        <div class="col3">
            3333
            <div class="col4">
                4444
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need it to look like when used:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

I also tried with grid-template-areas but I have not achieved the expected results.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with CSS.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was possible with html/css either @Paulie_D but got thinking about it, check out my new answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### Correction on old answer.

Okay so my last answer I read your question wrong to say "I can modify it" instead of "I can**'t** modify it", I do apologize for that.

### New Answer

Here is how you would achieve that grid like structure given the children were all top level with that css styling. It involves just a little bit of math and is a bit harder to maintain if things change, but will give the **exact** same result as the grid div.

```css
.col1{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px,1fr) minmax(600px,3fr);
}
.col2{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px,1fr) minmax(400px,2fr);
}
.col3{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(200px,1fr) minmax(200px,1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="col1">
    1111
    <div class="col2">
        2222
        <div class="col3">
            3333
            <div class="col4">
                4444
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Explanation

So in your example of using a grid with a min max repeated, we must consider that each element will be a minimum of 200 and a maximum of 1fr... Therefore because they are nested col1 must be the width of all of them... 
So it must be have 2 children (it's content and the other divs), first it's child should have a minmax of 200px and 1fr because we want it to be a minimum of 200px the 1fr works because the second child has a min max of 3 times (for the other 3 children) that of the first child... Which gives the illusion of 4 columns... If you had 5 children you could walk through the same calculations.
[Here](https://codepen.io/Trevor-Sharp-the-sans/pen/ZEPOjJO) is a Codepen demonstrating how the size of the div always matches that of the other css styles you provided and will continue to stay the same size. It's a bit redundant in how the classes are defined, but I wouldn't count on another solution in pure html/css.
Hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate it using flexbox

```css
[class*=col] {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col1">
  1111
  <div class="col2">
    2222
    <div class="col3">
      3333
      <div class="col4">
        4444
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```